# Where does `ng new appName` create the project?

Tags: angular

After upgrading my Angular CLI to 6.0.7, doing an `ng new appName` creates the project files in the current directory I am in! It used to create the project files under a newly created `appName` folder. What happened? Is it just me or some changes took place with the new CLI?